# Include the content of a file in JSP

Tags: jsp

I would like to include the content of a file inside an JSP page.
Usually, I would use something like:

```
<jsp:include page="<%= path_to_file %>" />
```

However, this will not work here since the file I am trying to include
is outside the web deployment.

The ugliest solution I've seen is something like this:

```
<td>
<% BufferedReader  br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path_to_file)));
   String line = br.readLine();
   while (line != null) { %>
     <% out.println(line); %>
     <% line = br.readLine(); } %>
</td>
<% } catch (IOException e) { %>
<td>
  <%= e %>
</td>
<% } %>
```

But I *really* don't want to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You *could* include a symbolic path in your distribution to point to your external path.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the ugly scriptlet code, you could write a small tag (in Java, extending `SimpleTagSupport`) just for including arbitrary files from your external path.

Then you could write

```
<my:include page="<%= path_to_file %>" />
```